# How to group nasted array in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In my mongodb collection I have next records

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d0dfb68264b2d01a3237a3e"), "name" : "lexa", "cat" : 2, "gender" : "male", "date" : ISODate("2019-06-22T09:56:56.070Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d0dfb6c264b2d01a3237a3f"), "name" : "dima", "cat" : 2, "gender" : "male", "date" : ISODate("2019-06-22T09:57:00.925Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d0dfb75264b2d01a3237a40"), "name" : "lena", "cat" : 2, "gender" : "female", "date" : ISODate("2019-06-22T09:57:10.003Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d0dfb7a264b2d01a3237a41"), "name" : "nina", "cat" : 2, "gender" : "female", "date" : ISODate("2019-06-22T09:57:14.941Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d0dfb8f264b2d01a3237a42"), "name" : "nina", "cat" : 1, "gender" : "female", "date" : ISODate("2019-06-22T09:57:35.128Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d0dfb93264b2d01a3237a43"), "name" : "lena", "cat" : 1, "gender" : "female", "date" : ISODate("2019-06-22T09:57:39.789Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d0dfb9b264b2d01a3237a44"), "name" : "dima", "cat" : 1, "gender" : "male", "date" : ISODate("2019-06-22T09:57:47.150Z")
```

Then I use aggregation mongo framework to group that records by cat.

```
db.foo.aggregate([{'$group': 
    {
        '_id': '$cat', 
        'users': 
            {'$push': 
                {
                    'name':'$name', 
                    'gender': '$gender'
                }
            }
    }
}])
```

That query returns me next result

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "users" : [
        {
            "name" : "nina",
            "gender" : "female"
        },
        {
            "name" : "lena",
            "gender" : "female"
        },
        {
            "name" : "dima",
            "gender" : "male"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "users" : [
        {
            "name" : "lexa",
            "gender" : "male"
        },
        {
            "name" : "dima",
            "gender" : "male"
        },
        {
            "name" : "lena",
            "gender" : "female"
        },
        {
            "name" : "nina",
            "gender" : "female"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the question is what I need to add to my query to group by my users array. I want to get something like this

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "users" : [
        {
            "gender": "male",
            "names": ["dima"]
        },
        {
            "gender": "female",
            "names": ["lena", "nina"]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "users" : [
        {
            "gender": "male",
            "names": ["lexa", "dima"]
        },
        {
            "gender": "female",
            "names": ["lena", "nina"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to have my nested array been  grouped too without loosing first group result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be easier to first group by cat X gender and then restructure the data like so :

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{'$group': 
    {
        '_id': {cat: '$cat', gender: "$gender"}, 
        'names': 
            {'$push': 
                {
                    'name':'$name', 
                }
            }
    }
},
{
 $group: {
     '_id': "$_id.cat",
     users: { $push: { gender: "$_id.gender", names: "$names" }
 }
}
])
```

Comment: Thanks. It what actually I want )